# Ruby gsub with index/offset?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, gsub

Does Ruby's [String#gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) method provide a means for including the index of the replacement?  For example, given the following string:

> I like you, you, you, and you.

I want to end up with this output:

> I like you1, you2, you3, and you4.

I know I can use `\1`, `\2`, etc. for matching characters in parentheses, but is there anything like `\i` or `\n` that would provide the number of the current match?

It's worth mentioning that my actual term is not as simple as "you", so an alternate approach that assumes the search term is static will not suffice.

Comment: Example code assuming `"you"` is easily modified by you to substitute any needed target or regex in its place.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

We can chain `with_index` to `gsub()` to get:

```
foo = 'I like you, you, you, and you.'.gsub(/\byou\b/).with_index { |m, i| "#{m}#{1+i}" }
puts foo
```

which outputs:

```
I like you1, you2, you3, and you4.
```

Comment: Both `each_with_index` and `with_index` are unsung-heroes.

Comment: I admit I ignored the latest!

Comment: I didn't even notice `with_index` can be used with `sub` and `gsub`!

Comment: I thought this was super cool! `foo = 'I like you, you, you, and you.'.gsub(/\byou\b/).with_index { |m, i| i == 2 ? "#{m}#{1+i}" : "#{m}" }`, outputs `#=> "I like you, you, you3, and you."`

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you :)

Comment: Hey, you1! You are genius! :D

Answer (score 4):

This is a little bit hacky, but you can use a variable that you increment inside of a block passed into gsub

```
source = 'I like you, you, you, and you.'
counter = 1
result = source.gsub(/you/) do |match|
  res = "#{match}#{counter}"
  counter += 1
  res
end

puts result
#=> I like you1, you2, you3, and you4.
```

Comment: same (ugly!) answer, same time => +1 :)

Comment: What if the replacement string includes values like `\1` as well?  How can I properly replace that with `$1` in the matched string?  e.g.: `"hello".gsub(/(ello)/, "i and h\1")` will produce "hi and hello".  How can I take these replacements into account within the block?

Comment: @MattHuggins: The block is called for each group. Using `"i and h#{match}"` will produce what you are looking for

Comment: I'm curious why someone would downvote. A comment would be helpful so I could address the issue

Answer (score 3):

This works but it's ugly:

```
n = 0; 
"I like you, you, you, and you.".gsub("you") { val = "you" + n.to_s; n+=1; val }
=> "I like you0, you1, you2, and you3."
```

Comment: What if the replacement string includes values like \1 as well? How can I properly replace that with $1 in the matched string? e.g.: "hello".gsub(/(ello)/, "i and h\1") will produce "hi and hello". How can I take these replacements into account within the block?